# Why one tensorflow model predicts different probs and Y for the same data?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I try to predict labels (36 classes) for different messages. I use LSTM and tensorflow for Keras. When I predict labels (Y) for 11 messages I get some results. But when I predict labels for 59 messages (11 + 48 new rows) predcitions for those 11 change...

Network is simple:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, input_length=max_length),
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(embedding_dim2, dropout=0.5, recurrent_dropout=0.5),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_class, activation='softmax')])


model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
rnn= model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs= nb_epoch, batch_size=batch_size,validation_split=0.1, shuffle=True)

score = model.evaluate(X_test,y_test)
```

After the training I test the model on unlabeled data. I used W2V and typical model.predict(unlabeled_data) function. Here are the results

(Y)label
30
28
1
28
31
27
31
30
30
30
0

Results for first eleven when I add new 38 rows.

(Y)label
**28
30
28
28
27
1
31
31
0
28
31**
31
31
28
31
31
27
30
4
...

Anyone has idea what I did wrong? As far as I know, dealing with easier frames (Sklearn), results for the same messages should not differ if I use the same model. The same story in Jupyter and PyCharm (production code).

I appreciate any help.

How do I prepare data and make prediction?

Loading from csv

```
data = pd.read_csv("path", sep=';', usecols=['text'])

X = data['text']

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=top_words)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(X)
sequences_train = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X)

word_index = tokenizer.word_index

X_padded = sequence.pad_sequences(sequences_train, maxlen=mxlen)
```

And then I predict

```
prediction = model.predict(X_padded)
df_prediction = pd.DataFrame(prediction)
df_prediction['num_max'] = df_prediction.max(axis=1)

df_prediction['label'] = df_prediction.idxmax(axis=1)
pred = df_prediction.iloc[:, 37:39]
print(pred)
```

In the next trail I change the input, but the code remains the same.

Comment: Maybe someone else can give a better or more detailed answer, but usually this stems from issues of randomness. By setting random seeds for NumPy and setting random_state arguments when possible you can better replicate results. It's the inherent randomness in initializing a network that causes the issue.

Comment: But during predictions the weights shouldn't be changing, right?

Comment: All right, but when I re-run predict for the same input (11 messages twice) predictions remain the same. The prediciton changes only if 11 messages are part of larger set... I use the same tokenizer and W2V...

Comment: @mb0850 what do you mean weights? I do not use wieghts (to balance data) in this example? Maybe I did not understand sth...

Comment: Just to be sure I understand what you are saying, while predicting, you are passing 11 sentences/sequences and getting 11 predictions. Then you are appending the 11 sequences with 48 more rows and getting total 59 predictions, but you see that the first 11 of 59 predictions don't match with the earlier predictions, and I am assuming you didn't re-train your model in-between the predictions. Is that correct?

Comment: @mb0850 exactly. I do not touch the model in-between.

Comment: can you give us the code for populating the `unlabeled_data` variable and the code where you are doing the 2 predictions back to back

Comment: I load data with pandas from csv. Than I name variable: X = data['text'], tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=top_words)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(X)  
sequences_train = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X)

word_index = tokenizer.word_index

X_padded = sequence.pad_sequences(sequences_train, maxlen=mxlen)    Than I predict prediction = model.predict(X_padded)      Next, I return to DataFrame: df_prediction = pd.DataFrame(prediction)
df_prediction['num_max'] = df_prediction.max(axis=1); df_prediction['label'] = df_prediction.idxmax(axis=1)
pred = df_prediction.iloc[:, 37:39]
print(pred)

Comment: Let me present it in more digestable way... :)

Comment: @mb0850 I put it above. Simple data split with sklearn: X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)    and W2V use from gensim: word2vec_model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('path/file.txt', binary=False)

embedding_matrix = word2vec_model.wv.syn0   ;   top_words = embedding_matrix.shape[0]
mxlen = 300
nb_classes = 36

Answer (score 4):

Tokenizer should be fitted on the training data and your test/prediction data should be tokenized with that Tokenizer.

From your code, it seems you are creating a new tokenizer and fitting it on test data which you are passing for prediction to your model (which was trained on data tokenized by a different tokenizer).

On top of that, the `num_words` argument of the `Tokenizer` selects the top most common words from the corpus of data it was fitted on. However since your prediction data has a different tokenizer (fitted on the just the test corpus), it probably has completely different top most common words.

Code Change:

```
# tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=top_words) # remove line
# tokenizer.fit_on_texts(X)  #remove line
```

Then use the tokenizer that you used to tokenize your training data to tokenize (`texts_to_sequences()`) your test data.

(*Note: This suggestion is strictly based on the code snippet provided in the question*)

Comment: I will test it during the day and I'll get back with the results here. For now, many, many thanks!!!

Comment: Holy... @mb850 You are right!!! Now it works... What an unconscious mistake... Great thanks again!